# The code flow stops after receiving a promise

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a simple function that validates a token on a user record.

```
@Get("confirm/:token")
    verifyEmail(@Param("token") token: string, @Res() res: Request) {
        console.log("confirm called")
        console.log(token);
        const user = this.userRepository.findOne({where: {token: token}});
        console.log("user promise")
        return res.res?.redirect("/home/welcome");
    }
```

when i run the code i can see in the console "user promise" but no  progress at all, what could posibily be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You inject the `Response` object but tell Typescript that you use the `Request` object, so Typescript can't warn you that `res.res.redirect` isn't actually what's right there. You should be using the `Response` type from `express` and call `res.redirect` instead of `res.res?.redirect`.

The reason you get no error is the optional operator, if the object you access is null or undefined, it doesn't go any further in the execution.

Or, as you found out, you can use the `@Redirect()` decorator, just make sure to remove the `@Res()` injection as it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

i was able to resolve my issue by using the Redirect() decorator as follows

```
@Get("confirm/:token")
    @Redirect('http://localhost:3000/home/welcome', 301)
    verifyEmail(@Param("token") token: string, @Res() res: Request) {
        console.log("confirm called")
        console.log(token);
        const user = this.userRepository.findOne({where: {token: token}});
        console.log("user promise")
        user.then((u) => console.log(u));
        return res.res?.redirect("/home/welcome");
    }
```